# How can I get and post the values of star rating directive in json with ng-resource?

Tags: angularjs

```html
<html>
<head>
 <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.14/angular.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<style>
.rating {
    color: #a9a9a9;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
ul.rating {
    display: inline-block;
}
.rating li {
    list-style-type: none;
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 1px;
    text-align: center;
    font-weight: bold;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.rating .filled {
    color: red;
}
</style>
</head>


 <body ng-app="starApp">
    <div ng-controller="StarCtrl"> <span ng-repeat="rating in ratings">{{rating.current}} out of
            {{rating.max}}
        <div star-rating rating-value="rating.current" max="rating.max" on-rating-selected="getSelectedRating(rating)"></div>
        </span>
    </div>

  <script>
var starApp = angular.module('starApp', []);

starApp.controller('StarCtrl', ['$scope', function ($scope) {
    $scope.rating = 0;
    $scope.ratings = [{
        current: 5,
        max: 10
    }];

    $scope.getSelectedRating = function (rating) {
        console.log(rating);
    }
}]);

starApp.directive('starRating', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        template: '<ul class="rating">' +
            '<li ng-repeat="star in stars" ng-class="star" ng-click="toggle($index)">' +
            '\u2605' +
            '</li>' +
            '</ul>',
        scope: {
            ratingValue: '=',
            max: '=',
            onRatingSelected: '&'
        },
        link: function (scope, elem, attrs) {

            var updateStars = function () {
                scope.stars = [];
                for (var i = 0; i < scope.max; i++) {
                    scope.stars.push({
                        filled: i < scope.ratingValue
                    });
                }
            };

            scope.toggle = function (index) {
                scope.ratingValue = index + 1;
                scope.onRatingSelected({
                    rating: index + 1
                });
            };

            scope.$watch('ratingValue', function (oldVal, newVal) {
                if (newVal) {
                    updateStars();
                }
            });
        }
    }
});
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

I want to use this star rating directive but I am clueless about how to use get and post using ng-resource so that i can fetch and push the selected values in my json file.

Also I want to ask that what's the benefit of using this instead of scope?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Your issue was that your callback function on your controller wasn't triggered.

You can modify this as shown below:

```html
<html>
<head>
 <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.14/angular.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<style>
.rating {
    color: #a9a9a9;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
ul.rating {
    display: inline-block;
}
.rating li {
    list-style-type: none;
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 1px;
    text-align: center;
    font-weight: bold;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.rating .filled {
    color: red;
}
</style>
</head>


 <body ng-app="starApp">
    <div ng-controller="StarCtrl"> <span ng-repeat="rating in ratings">{{rating.current}} out of
            {{rating.max}}
        <div star-rating rating-value="rating.current" max="rating.max" on-rating-selected="getSelectedRating"></div>
        </span>
    </div>

  <script>
var starApp = angular.module('starApp', []);

starApp.controller('StarCtrl', ['$scope', function ($scope) {
    $scope.rating = 0;
    $scope.ratings = [{
        current: 5,
        max: 10
    }];

    $scope.getSelectedRating = function (rating) {
        console.log(rating);
    }
}]);

starApp.directive('starRating', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        template: '<ul class="rating">' +
            '<li ng-repeat="star in stars" ng-class="star" ng-click="toggle($index)">' +
            '\u2605' +
            '</li>' +
            '</ul>',
        scope: {
            ratingValue: '=',
            max: '=',
            onRatingSelected: '&'
        },
        link: function (scope, elem, attrs) {

            var updateStars = function () {
                scope.stars = [];
                for (var i = 0; i < scope.max; i++) {
                    scope.stars.push({
                        filled: i < scope.ratingValue
                    });
                }
            };

            scope.toggle = function (index) {
                scope.ratingValue = index + 1;
                //console.log(scope.onRatingSelected);
                scope.onRatingSelected()(index + 1);
            };

            scope.$watch('ratingValue', function (oldVal, newVal) {
                if (newVal) {
                    updateStars();
                }
            });
        }
    }
});
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Honestly I don't know why it works... :/

There is a plunk which shows another way to do this: http://plnkr.co/edit/2mrW4SfRrI0qng7ORF0i

Comment: yup will try this example on plunk. Thanks